# Uploading a csv file to a server and then reading from it

Tags: java, web-applications, csv, oracle10g

I'm trying to develop a web application in Java wherein I need to populate a database using a csv file. I've used csv reader to achieve this. The application is working like a charm as long as csv file is in the server where the application is located. While accessing the application from another site, I get an error saying that the file is not found. How do I read directly from the client machine or how to import the file to the server and then read from it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are going to have to send the file to the server. How you do this depends on what exactly your java code looks like. If you are using an MVC framework, you could just use the HTML file input field, if not then, well once again it depends a lot on what your Java app is. Applet? Desktop application? Using Swing? Another framework?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I'm running the jsp page in using tomcat and presently I've used the HTML file input field to get the path of the csv file. As with any webapp, the server searches for the path in it's(the server's) local directory for the csv file and returns an error saying the file was not found. And yeah, am using an MVC framework for it and the application will be accessed using a website. I hope I'm clear on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a csv file is same as uploading a normal file.. you can use html file input field for this. You will have to write a seperate server side implementation to receive the file and store it some where in the server.
Now you have the file with you for processing. Read it and update the database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now, am trying to load the file onto the server. Will update if am successful. Is there any default package sort of thing that will aid in the transfer of files? Thanks again!

Comment: There is nothing like that. just google for file upload java.. You will get the required code.

Comment: Got it working now. I'm using a piece of code to get the file from the client to the server and storing it locally and reading from it in the local drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file using ftp or sftp(secure ftp) from client machine. 
The below link may be useful
[http://wiki.jsch.org/index.php?Manual%2FExamples%2FSftpFileCopyExample](http://wiki.jsch.org/index.php?Manual/Examples/SftpFileCopyExample)